# Spring - AspectJ pointcut for constructor object with annotation

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm developing a java (JDK1.6) application with Spring framework(4.0.5) and AspectJ for AOP Logging.

My Aspect classes work fine but I can't create a pointcut for constructor object.

This is my object:

```
@Controller
public class ApplicationController {
    public ApplicationController(String myString, MyObject myObject) {
        ...
    }
    ...
    ..
    .
}
```

This is my Aspect class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class CommonLogAspect implements ILogAspect {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CommonLogAspect.class);

    // @Before("execution(my.package.Class.new(..)))
    @Before("execution(* *.new(..))")
    public void constructorAnnotatedWithInject() {
        log.info("CONSTRUCTOR");
    }
}
```

How can I create a pointcut for my constructor object?

---

Thanks

Comment: @kocko the `"` there are, I've missed them when I was typing the question.

Comment: I don't believe you can intercept the constructor call in pure Spring AOP.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis how can I intercept the constructor call ?

Comment: Maybe with AspectJ instrumentation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you make me an example or link a guide? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about AspectJ. But I think that's what you should follow through on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Sotirios Delimanolis* is right insofar as Spring AOP does not support constructor interception, you do need full AspectJ for it. The Spring manual, chapter [9.8 Using AspectJ with Spring applications](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj), describes how to use it with LTW (load-time weaving).

Furthermore, there is a problem with your pointcut

```java
@Before("execution(* *.new(..))")
```

Constructors do not have return types like methods in AspectJ syntax, so you need to remove the leading `*`:

```java
@Before("execution(*.new(..))")
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed - I assumed that constructor calls would be picked up by a statement like the first one above.